# PyCharm - Django tutorial autocompleting in HTML files

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, pycharm

I'm currently working through the Django tutorial, and I've found something that's a bit troublesome and I'm not sure if there's a workaround. This is an HTML file opened up in PyCharm, and there are two models that I've created: Question and Choice.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ question.question_text }}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
<ul>
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice. }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

When I get to this part, there are no suggestions being shown for choice, even though there is stuff there.

```
        <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice. }}</li>
```

For example, the part that I haven't finished is supposed to be choice.votes, but I have to type .votes manually because it doesn't autocomplete.

But, I'm able to autocomplete the question_text for question. Is there a reason that the autocomplete doesn't work for choice? Is there any way to "fix" it, or is that just the intended behavior?

I've only just started programming in Python but I've worked on several large projects in Java and I know that without Eclipse's autocomplete for Java variables it'd be a huge pain to remember the names of every variable.

Like, for the tutorial the Choice model just has a couple fields, but what if I'm working on something larger that has hundreds of variables? Do I just have to manually remember the variable names when using them in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, PyCharm doesn't autocomplete django template syntax because it has no clue which view will be rendering the template. So it has no clue what to expect as far as context goes.

That being said, I imagine your autocomplete came from your `<title>` tag above the `<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>`. You've already accessed `question_text` from `question` before, so PyCharm is aware that the `question` object contains `question_text`.

PyCharm's autocomplete in .py files is generally very good, but yes, in templates you'll be accessing attributes without the help of autocomplete.

Comment: Try the latest version. The What's New in PyCharm video shows an example of this.

Comment: @PaulEveritt I enthusiastically installed the new PyCharm upon release of the update, but unfortunately I get 'Cannot find declaration to go to' if I ever try to use these features, and autocomplete in the template (at least in my configuration) doesn't seem to work. That being said, I'm aware of your role with PyCharm and I cannot express enough how much I love PyCharm. If there's a specific configuration that does enable autocomplete of model fields in a template, I'd love to see your answer. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Thanks for the kinds words. Can you put some tiny Djano project in a repo on GitHub and maybe I can take a look. Also, remember that this is a PyCharm Professional feature.

Answer (score 1):

@rococo, you'll need to setup you app into the Pycharm.

Go into File / Settings / Languages and Frameworks / Django.

**In the screen that appear, do the actions below:**

```
-> Mark "Enable Django Support"

-> Fill Django Project root with: "your project root folder"

-> Fill Settings with: "your settings file into the project"

-> Fill Manage script with: "manage.py"
```

That's it, you probably are ready to develop a little bit faster and confortable.
Best regards!